# Checking if two lists share at least one element

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, for example:

```
a = ["mail1", "mail2", "mail3", "mail4"]
b = ["mail2", "mail5"]
```

and I want to check if any of the elements in list `b` also appears in list `a`.

I wanted to know if there is a way (and what is it) to do this without a for loop.

Also I wanted to know how can I create a list of boolean values, where each value will be the result of the comparison of values `a[i]` and `b[i]`, something like:

```
[z for i, j in zip(a, b)  z = i == j] # (just with the right syntax)
```

`z` will be `1` if in some place `i == j`, so I can check the array for any 'True' values.

Comment: Please mention what have you tried with python? Some code will be convenient!

Comment: Please keep it to *one* question per post. Your first is answered by using [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). Your second is almost there: `[i == j for i, j in zip(a, b)]`, but that'll be limited to the shortest length of the two lists. E.g. it'll return `[False, False]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `any`:

```
any(x in a for x in b)
```

The nice thing about this generator expression is that `any` will return `True` as soon as the generator yields a `True`, i.e. there won't be redundant `x in a` lookups.

Edit:

You can improve the time complexity by making a set from `a`.

```
a_set = set(a)
any(x in a_set for x in b)
```

---

Regarding your new question:

```
[x == y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Comment: What is the actual syntax of the any function? I tried to use it as `return any(x in a for x in b);` but it reports back from missiong ')', identifiers and semicolon.

Comment: @Bobys `any` takes an iterable and checks whether any element of that iterable is truthy (i.e. `bool(element) ==  True`).  Your statement is syntactically correct (the iterable is a generator expression) so the error you are getting must come from somewhere else.

Answer (score 9):

Elegant way is to use sets:

```
a = ["mail1", "mail2", "mail3", "mail4"]
b = ["mail2", "mail5"]

anb = set(a) & set(b)

print anb

if anb:
    print True

>>> set(['mail2'])
>>> True
```

Comment: definitely takes longer to build a two sets from non-trivial lists (in most cases) than it does to run a genexp in `any`

Comment: Of course it does, it is just a smart way to get difference and to check it. Just wanted to show it, because too many people don't know how awesome sets are.

Answer (score 0):

The any function takes in an iterable [(See documentation here)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), so the answer should be `any([x in a for x in b])`