# Checking if lists share one or more elements in Racket

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I have two lists, `lst1` and `lst2`. I want to define a function to check if they share some elements. For example:

- `(share-some-elements? '(a b) '(a c))` ⇒ true
- `(share-some-elements? '(a b) '(d e f))` ⇒ false
- `(share-some-elements? '(a b) '(a b d e))` ⇒ true

I have an implementation:

```
(define (share-some-elements? lst1 lst2)
  (ormap (λ (x) (member x lst1)) lst2))
```

Which checks if each element in `lst2` is a member of `lst1`, and returns true if any of them is.

My questions are:

1. What are the other ways of doing this?
2. How can I extend this to support any number of lists? ie.

   - `(all-share-some-elements? '(a b) '(a c) '(a d))` ⇒ true
   - `(all-share-some-elements? '(a b) '(a c) '(b d))` ⇒ false
   - `(all-share-some-elements? '(a b) '(a c) '(b d a))` ⇒ true

There is a similar question on how to do this on two lists in python:
[Checking if two lists share at least one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270711/checking-if-two-lists-share-at-least-one-element), which doesn't quite answer my questions.

Comment: You could use [set-intersection](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fset..rkt%29._set-intersect%29%29), which works on multiple lists. If the intersection is not empty, then you have elements in common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both questions can be solved using a single procedure that takes a variable number of arguments. Assuming that at least one list is passed, we have:

```
(define (all-share-some-elements? . lists)
  (not (null? (apply set-intersect lists))))
```

Explanation:

- We apply [`set-intersect`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fset..rkt%29._set-intersect%29%29) on all the lists.
- If after the intersection the result is non-empty, then the lists share at least one element in common.

Using your examples:

```
(all-share-some-elements? '(a b) '(a c))
=> #t
(all-share-some-elements? '(a b) '(d e f))
=> #f
(all-share-some-elements? '(a b) '(a b d e))
=> #t

(all-share-some-elements? '(a b) '(a c) '(a d))
=> #t
(all-share-some-elements? '(a b) '(a c) '(b d))
=> #f
(all-share-some-elements? '(a b) '(a c) '(b d a))
=> #t
```

Comment: What's wrong with `(not (null? (apply set-intersect lists)))` ?

Comment: @uselpa nothing, just that I wasn't aware that `set-intersect` worked on plain lists. It's fixed now :)